# Netbeans/Maven development: how to make it faster?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, junit

I'm using Maven for the heavy lifting. However, when working on small parts (like unit tests), the reaction time of "mvn test" inside Netbeans is too slow. I have already written a ClassReloader that sets up directory watches and uses Netbeans' compile-on-save. However, that is a bit clumsy because it requires me to modify the test unit class and add a main method.

Is there a nicer way? I already thought of setting up a parallel view of the same modules, one that uses ant build scripts. You guys have any better idea? Or tools to make that easier?

For example, the maven-dependency-plugin is able to copy dependencies and write the classpath to a file. That's a start. But how do I import the classpath into the ant build file, or even better, into the netbeans project configuration? And what about the system props set up in the configuration section of the maven-surefire-plugin?

There is the maven-ant-plugin, however it has nearly no configuration options and it does not work without modifying the output files.

Are there better tools? Maybe a netbeans project generator that transforms maven projects into netbeans project configurations?

Then there is yet another problem: you cannot use the same source folder twice in netbeans, not even if the other instance is inside a not currently open project group....

The solution need not be perfect: like I said, it is only needed for the small parts.

Maybe I start using Eclipse for the simple and small stuff.

I won't start discussing about what's better, Netbeans eclipse etc. I use Netbeans because it is the only IDE with native Maven support. Eclipse's maven support is crap and I wasted too much time already because of it being that way.

Comment: Do use Eclipse or Intellij. Don't use Netbeans. For anything.

Comment: If you use the Eclipse WTP distributable, maven support is included, and doesn't have any of the limitations you list of NetBeans.

Comment: what do you mean you are using maven for the heavy lifting? Is there a noticeable difference running `mvn test` from the command line? Why does performance of tests matter, is it affecting functionality of the tests?

Answer (score 0):

Typically while mvn test (running all tests) is as slow as running on the command line, running single tests should be significantly faster with Compile on Save turned on. You would just effectively execute surefire:surefire  via mvn as the classes were compiled for you on the fly. It still does take up to a few seconds, as new JVM is created, maven project loaded and surefire goal is executed which again spawns another jvm, your mileage may vary.

You can trigger the Run Test action while having both the test or tested class in editor.